# Why are timestamps being saved in psql but not able to be accessed? How to access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I type psql 'db-name' and go select created_at from orders;
I can see that the orders have created_at datetimes.
However, when I go in the ruby on rails console and type Order.first, it says created_at is nil. Why can't I read the data in the database?

Comment: Do you have `timestamps` added in migration when creating table?

Comment: @aldrien.h

    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

Do I need to have it specifically timestamps?

Comment: @Tristan that means you have an issue in pql config or schema